# How to create a custom data source in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to allow administrator to import data from a third-party service. To do that I want to list all possible things to import in admin panel and allow administrator to choose what to import.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = #...
    length = #...
    #...

class ImportManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        # what should go here?

class MovieImporter(Movie):
    objects = ImportManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name = 'Import Movies'

admin.site.register(Movie)
admin.site.register(ImportMovie)
```

I'm confused about how can I return a QuerySet from ImportManager.all if there is no even database and its not clear from documentation is it possible just to pass a list of objects to QuerySet. Any ideas?

Comment: My summary of what you want: a new model class implemented with an external, probably read-only, "database" as its backend. I also imagine that you want to import the movies into your main database? Having a separate `ImportManager` in the `Movie` class seems to me more likely to be what you want - `Movie.import_objects` or similar.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, yes, this is what I want to do. But having `ImportManager` in a `Movie` wouldn't allow me to display a list of possible imports separately in admin panel. The problem is in showing this possible imports to admin, not the importing itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably going to be hard to get the built-in admin to work with an external non-SQL "database" (unless you write a custom DB backend, maybe using [django-nonrel](http://django-nonrel.org/), or make a manager-like object that returns implements all the methods the admin wants to use in ways [like okm suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10091385/344821)).

You might be able to hack it, but I bet your time will be better spent just [adding a custom view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites) for doing imports. You can inherit from the admin templates and make it look pretty similar to the rest of the admin site.

Comment: Thanks, building a custom views turns out to be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could mock an evaluated QuerySet by

```
qs = Movie.objects.get_queryset()
qs._result_cache = map(lambda x: Movie(*x),
     [(1, 'The Godfather', '175'), ...])
```

and show it in an admin changelist. However, you have to hack QuerySet methods and disable admin operations such as filters to prevent extra real DB query.

For simplicity, why not just sync data to local DB and store them w/ extra state field which has value such as "admin picked"?
Or you could put the data in another table and sync the picked to the movie table.

Another straight way is to allow staff to pickup/filter by movie category and other possible meta conditions in changelist or your customized view and perform the sync of Movie info in Celery task later.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing your own manager. What you have to do in the methods of your manager, is just some especial querys to the database.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/

Here you have some examples on how you can create some methods for a custom manager.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, I've had read the docs on manager, they aren't helpful at all, because there is no "database" actually. I use a third-party service to retrieve a list of possible imports.

Comment: But yes there is a database. Look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods, the method with_counts retreives database information using a custom query. I think I´m not understanding you